# Actionscript 3.0 network programming with C#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, networking, sockets

I was looking into network programming with AS3 and I noticed that all the examples were using Java to code a server. I tried using C# to make one but it wasn't working as expected. I was wondering, does anyone have a really simple example of AS3 networking using a C# server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use standard HTTP it doesn't matter what server language you use. Pass XML or JSON as the layer between and use the HTTPRequest as the Flex request method.

If you want to use the sockets layer, are you looking for something like this: http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid38B6B346DEFB346620FE375C9F610A9C5D020DA6.aspx?s=socket#L6 ?

Answer (score 1):

I think a good place to start gathering information would be the Adobe Developer Center, specifically the [Learn Flex and .NET](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_net.html) section. I know this is not exactly what you are asking for. It is more for Flex and ASP.NET, but maybe a good starting point.